# Sequelize failed to update datetime datatype in SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, datetime, electron, sequelize.js

I am trying to update SQL Server 2012 via sequelize CRM and getting the below error. My datatype for the column ins DateTime.

> (node:33100) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

**Configuration**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const config = require('../config/config');

// Override timezone formatting for MSSQL
Sequelize.DATE.prototype._stringify = function _stringify(date, options) {
    return this._applyTimezone(date, options).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS');
  };
  
class SequelizeConnection {
    connect() {
        const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config.options);
        sequelize
            .authenticate()
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
            });
        return sequelize
    }

    get() {
        return this.connect()
    }
}

const sequelize = new SequelizeConnection().get()

module.exports = sequelize;
```

in my model as below...

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require("../db/sequelize");


const User = sequelize.define('DB_USER', {
```

......
....

```
DATE_OF_BIRTH: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    notEmpty: true,
    allowNull: false,
},
```

.....

```
module.exports = User
```

My update command to the table as follows

```
else if (arg.table === 'users') {
        console.log(`table type is users ${arg.id} - ${arg.table}`)
        if (arg.type === 0) {

            User.update(data, {
                where: { USER_ID: arg.id },
            }).then(e => {}).then(e => {
                event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', _sync());
            })

        }
```

Comment: 1) SQL Server 2008 is now out of support - you should upgrade asap. 2) We'd need to see some code or configuration information - as the error says there is a string (somewhere) which represents a date, but which doesn't convert correctly. Whether this is a user input or framework issue we can't tell without additional information.

Comment: @DaleK i have updated my question. Can you please check?

Answer (score 1):

There are many string formats supported for date & time by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not. And also, the `DATETIME` datatype is notoriously picky about what string literals it considers valid dates&times.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible

Comment: If i change the datetime to datetime2 then existing data of the table will not be impacted? kindly advise.

Comment: @JSBeginner: should be converted to the new datatype just fine, since the new datatype covers everything the old one did - and more. But make a backup beforehand nonetheless!

Comment: @JSBeginner: if you feel this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.